# Does this summation formula for $\pi(x)$ work out? (Answer: no)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, recursion

Let $p_i$ be the $i$th prime number.  For $x \in \Bbb{R}, x \gt 0$, define:

$$
\Delta(x) =\left \{\prod_{i=1}^r q_i : \{q_1, \dots, q_r \}\subset \{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_{\pi(x)}\}\right\}
$$

Let $\omega$ be the little-omega function from number theory, and $\pi$ the prime-counting function.

We have the following chain of equalities:

$$
\pi(x) = \pi(\sqrt{x}) - 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{\pi(\sqrt{x})} (-1)^k \left( \sum_{f \in \Delta(\sqrt{x}) \\ \omega(f) = k} \ \ \sum_{g \in \Delta(\sqrt{x}) \\ f\ \mid\ g} 1 \right) \tag{1} 
$$

is another way of writing the first formula under ["Algorithms for
evalutation $\pi(x)$"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Algorithms_for_evaluating_%CF%80(x)). And this in turn equals:
$$
\pi(x) = \pi(\sqrt{x}) - 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{\pi(\sqrt{x})} (-1)^k \left( \sum_{g \in \Delta(\sqrt{x})} \ \ \sum_{f \in \Delta(\sqrt{x}) \\ f\ \mid\ g \\ \omega(f) = k} 1 \right) \tag{2} 
$$

which makes perfect sense to do so.  We then have:

$$
\pi(x) = \pi(\sqrt{x}) - 1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{\pi(\sqrt{x}) }(-1)^k \left( \sum_{g \in \Delta(\sqrt{x})}{\omega(g) \choose k }\right) \tag{3}
$$

That is because the range over $f \in \Delta(\sqrt{x})$ such that $f \mid g$ and $\omega(f) = k$ can be counted as ${\omega(g) \choose k}$ obviously.  But the expression ${\omega(g)\choose k}$ is independent of the choice of $g' \in \Delta(\sqrt{x})$ as long $\omega(g') = \omega(g)$.  And therefore we may change the sum to:

$$
\pi(x) = \pi(\sqrt{x}) - 1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{\pi(\sqrt{x})}(-1)^k \left( \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\pi(\sqrt{x})}{\pi(\sqrt{x}) \choose \ell }{\ell \choose k }\right) \tag{4}
$$

And of course the canonical form of the summation would then be:

$$
\pi(x) = \pi(\sqrt{x}) - 1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{\pi(\sqrt{x})} \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\pi(\sqrt{x})}(-1)^k{\pi(\sqrt{x}) \choose \ell }{\ell \choose k } \tag{5}
$$

> **Question.** Can we use the [properties of the binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) to further rearrange this summation?

Comment: I don’t see that first formula on the Wikipedia page. Can you be more soecific where it is? It’s a long page.

Comment: When I search on the page for the word “ways,” I don’t find anything. It might be something I have to click on?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I fixed the text of the link, but the link in my post (first link) goes directly to the proper section of the prime counting page on wikipedia.

Comment: It seems like you might require $g<x.$ That fouls up your formula, because not every element of $g\in \Delta$ is allowed just because $w(g)=k.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the sum over $k=0..\pi(\sqrt{x})$ can be replaced with a sum from $k =0.. \infty$ as well.  Don't know if that helps, and I don't fully understand your concern yet.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews could you explain more your concern so that I can work through it?  I think you may be wrong or at least have made a typo because I only say $\omega(f) = k$ as a condition not $\omega(g) = k$ anywhere.

Comment: @ExercisingMathematician Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see the [guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: There are no $g\in \Delta(\sqrt x)$ that have $w(g)>\pi(\sqrt x),$ so of course you can use more $k.$ The problem is that there are $g\in \Delta(\sqrt x)$ with $g>x$ contributing terms to this sum.

Comment: I don’t think your first formula works ever if you restrict to $g\leq x.$ You need to count *all* multiples $g$ of $f$ with $g\leq x,$ not just the square-free ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand $$(1+x+xy)^n$$ you get $$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\binom ni\binom ij x^iy^j$$

Letting $x=1,y=-1$ this gives you:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j\binom ni\binom ij =1
$$

So that would mean your formula is:

$$\pi(x)=\pi(\sqrt x)-1+1=\pi(\sqrt x)$$

The problem is your very first step. You have to restrict $g\leq x.$ Not every element of $\Delta(\sqrt x)$ is $\leq x.$